# Pass Dynamic String to HTML from CodeBehind

Tags: html, parameters, code-behind

I have a dynamic string that gets the server map path, lets call it strPath.
I'm trying to pass the value of this string to html by using <%strPath%> however it doesnt work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dont mind the string here is static, once I can successfuly show the picture I'll make it dynamic.

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string imagePath = Server.MapPath("../Uploads/" + "10.jpg");
        }




<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="<%imagePath%>" />
```

Comment: what language are you using for your code behind?

Comment: C#, and I'm trying to print an image on the page using this string as the img src.

Comment: Have you tried `<%= strPath%>`?

Comment: The server map path is your server location of the image, you need the internet location of the image for the url. if the image is stored on your site folder just give it your site url and the folder of the image, if not you will have to move it there

Comment: Dont use Server MppPath. just get the relative path to the image from your calling page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an `<asp:Image>` and set the ImageUrl property on server side?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
   </head>
  <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="dynamicImage">
      </div>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then on your code behide:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dynamicImage.ImageURL = http://YOURSITEURL/Images/YOURIMAGE.jpeg
    }
```

Comment: I've also tried asp:image and setting ImageURL however it did not work aswell.

Comment: <asp:image ImageURL = <%strPath%> runat="server" />

Comment: no, on your code behide page in the page load event set the url